# math direction changes inside `\underline` when using `babel` with `bidi`

Tags: luatex, babel, bidi, underline

I am using Latex to do my homework in our native language Hebrew, which is an rtl language. I am trying to migrate to `babel` with `lualatex` since I encountered annoying bugs with `polyglossia` and `xelatex` (plus, I think the syntax of `babel` is nicer compared to `polyglossia`).

I tried to compile a sample document and I found a weird issue. I tried to type an exponent in inline math mode inside an `underline` command and the exponent showed up on the left side instead of the right side as it should be with math exponents. It seems `babel` uses the default direction of the document (RTL in this case) instead of the proper direction for math inside an `underline`. This issue doesn't appear in regular text or in `\textbf`, `\textit`, or `\emph`. Here's a picture:
[image]

As you can see, only `\underline` produces wrong results while every other command works fine. Here's the code to generate this document:

```
% !TeX spellcheck = he_HE
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{extarticle}

\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage[bidi=basic, layout=counters tabular]{babel}

\babelprovide[main, import, alph=letters, Alph=letters]{hebrew}
\babelprovide[import]{english}

\babelfont[hebrew]{rm}[ItalicFont=*-Regular, ItalicFeatures={FakeSlant=0.3}]{Assistant}
\babelfont[hebrew]{sf}[ItalicFont=*-Regular, ItalicFeatures={FakeSlant=0.3}]{Assistant}

\AddToHook{begindocument/end}{\selectlanguage{hebrew}}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[intlimits]{esint}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{moreenum}
\usepackage{witharrows}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{derivative}

\NewDocumentCommand{\C}{}{\mathbb{C}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\Conjugate}{ s m }{
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{\pqty{#2}}{{#2}}^{\ast}
}

\begin{document}
המכפלה הפנימית הסטנדרטית מעל \(\C^n\):

\textbf{המכפלה הפנימית הסטנדרטית מעל \(\C^n\):}

\textit{המכפלה הפנימית הסטנדרטית מעל \(\C^n\) :}

\emph{המכפלה הפנימית הסטנדרטית מעל \(\C^n\) :}

\underline{המכפלה הפנימית הסטנדרטית מעל \(\C^n\):}
\[ \braket{u}{v} = \sum_{j = 1}^{n} \Conjugate{u}_j v_j \]
\end{document}
```

Can anyone explain why math expressions don't render in the proper direction in `\underline` and how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please provide shorter examples to the demonstrate a problem, it will help people to help you.

The problem can be reduced to the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[bidi=basic,hebrew,provide=*]{babel}

\babelfont[hebrew]{rm}{David CLM}

\begin{document}
    \underline{שלום $C^n$}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In section 1.24 of `babel`'s manual it is stated that adjustments for `\underline` are needed with `luatex`, and you can use these adjustments with the `layout = extras` option.

The problem is that [a few years ago](https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/commit/96832b85fe483a7d3209e75f86442f7458f7fe53#diff-5187be7e3233f8844e8427516e0b38b61ca8ebf4706bde7fbb985a21107e19c2R1143) `\underline` was robustified, and babel does not take that into account, so the option is broken. Luckily there an easy fix, just replace `\bbl@sreplace`, which is a command `babel` use internally to patch commands, but is not aware of robust commands, with `\xpatchcmd` of the [`xpatch`](https://ctan.org/pkg/xpatch) package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[bidi = basic, hebrew, provide=*, layout = tabular]{babel}

\babelfont[hebrew]{rm}{David CLM}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd\underline{$\@@underline}{\bgroup\bbl@nextfake$\@@underline}{}{}
\xpatchcmd\underline{$\relax}{$\egroup\relax}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \underline{שלום $C^n$}
\end{document}
```

or even witout ptaching, you can redefine `\underline`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[bidi = basic, hebrew, provide=*, layout = tabular]{babel}

\babelfont[hebrew]{rm}{David CLM}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand\underline[1]{%
    \relax
    \ifmmode\@@underline{#1}%
    \else 
    \bgroup\bbl@nextfake$\@@underline{\hbox{#1}}\m@th$\egroup\relax\fi} 
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \underline{שלום $C^n$}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that I added `layout = tabular` to `babel`'s options, and this is important. If the list of layouts is empty babel does not define `\bbl@nextfake`, so you will need to use at least one layout.

I have opened a [ticket](https://github.com/latex3/babel/issues/246), probably it will be fixed soon.

As a side note, the line `\AddToHook{begindocument/end}{\selectlanguage{hebrew}}` does not make much sense if you declared hebrew as the main language.

Comment: Unfortunately, the fix you provided causes the direction to reverse in display mode. It fixes `underline`, but now the important equations in display mode are broken.

Comment: @ShaiAvr, see my edit

Comment: Thank you. Works perfectly.